# FileLoadException was unhandled

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-blob-storage

i am working on a web service in MVC4 but evrytime i try to run the code i get this type of error.

"An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Note: i have already set my "COPY LOCAL" property to true but nothing has changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error typically means that a assembly that you uses are tying to use another version than the one that was loaded into your appdomain.

The error is usually resolved by adding an `<assemblyBinding>` to your web.config. Look through all config files that you can find in your solution. One of them probably has an assembly binding. Copy that binding to the web project.

The cause can also be that you have an `<assemblyBinding>`, but it directs to an incorrect version.

Comment: but isn't there a way to know which version is required by the code.....coz i am using all the updated ones

Comment: look in packages.conf

Comment: evrything is fine according to me and what u have mentioned but the error is still there ,actually i am all new to MVC so i was trying some code from open source from a website the link to that is here is the link to website : http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=891